# Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "form". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag

Tags: html

```html
<div class="container" novalidate>

  <form [formGroup]="profileData" (ngSubmit)="register()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="fname"  required>
    <div>


      <div *ngIf="profileData.controls['fname'].hasError('required')" class="alert alert-danger">
        **** can't left blank ****
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="profileData.controls['fname'].hasError('minlength')" class="alert alert-danger">
        **** minlength will be 3 ****
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="profileData.controls['fname'].hasError('maxlength')" class="alert alert-danger">
        **** maxlength should be 9 ****
      </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lname">
    </div> 


    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="uemail">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group" formGroupName="addr">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>city</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="ucity">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address Lane</label> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="uaddress">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" formControlName="gender"><b>male</b>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" formControlName="gender"><b>female</b>
    </div>
  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>country</label>
      <select class="form-control" formControlName="ucountry">
        <option value="india">india</option>
        <option value="usa">usa</option>
        <option value="canada">canada</option>
        <option value="dubai">dubai</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
    
  </form>
</div>
```

it showing like this...

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "form". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("

[ERROR ->]

where should i mistaken in this..?

Answer (score 4):

Seems you are not closing the div tag here

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="fname" required>
  <div><!-- this is not closed, replace with </div>-->
```

Instead of

Comment: Just beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Line 7

```
 <form [formGroup]="profileData" (ngSubmit)="register()">
<div class="form-group">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="fname"  required>
<div> <!-- Here -->
```

Close the last div tag

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="container" novalidate>
  <form [formGroup]="profileData" (ngSubmit)="register()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="fname"  required>
    </div>


      <div *ngIf="profileData.controls['fname'].hasError('required')" class="alert alert-danger">
        **** can't left blank ****
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="profileData.controls['fname'].hasError('minlength')" class="alert alert-danger">
        **** minlength will be 3 ****
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="profileData.controls['fname'].hasError('maxlength')" class="alert alert-danger">
        **** maxlength should be 9 ****
      </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lname">
    </div> 


    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="uemail">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group" formGroupName="addr">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>city</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="ucity">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address Lane</label> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="uaddress">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" formControlName="gender"><b>male</b>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" formControlName="gender"><b>female</b>
    </div>
  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>country</label>
      <select class="form-control" formControlName="ucountry">
        <option value="india">india</option>
        <option value="usa">usa</option>
        <option value="canada">canada</option>
        <option value="dubai">dubai</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
    
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to already be answered.